# kubuntu muon package manager stop working

Tags: kubuntu, muon-package-manager

i have kubuntu today after updating the muon package manager stuck at 64% so i closes it.
and after that when i try to update or reinstall or install software the manger stuck.
so how can i reinstall the muon package manger from terminal??

i try

> sudo apt-get  install muon

and i get this messege

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
muon is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libopencv-dev : Depends: libopencv-core-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-ml-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-imgproc-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-video-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-objdetect-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-gpu-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-calib3d-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-flann-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-features2d-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-legacy-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-contrib-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

so what to do, i need to reinstall it because it not working

```
~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libopencv-dev:
 libopencv-dev depends on libopencv-core-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1); however:
  Package libopencv-core-dev is not installed.
 libopencv-dev depends on libopencv-ml-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1); however:
  Package libopencv-ml-dev is not installed.
 libopencv-dev depends on libopencv-imgproc-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1); however:
  Package libopencv-imgproc-dev is not installed.
 libopencv-dev depends on libopencv-video-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1); however:
  Package libopencv-video-dev is not installed.
 libopencv-dev depends on libopencv-objdetect-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1); however:
  Package libopencv-objdetect-dev is not installed.
 libopencv-dev depends on libopencv-gpu-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1); however:
  Package libopencv-gpu-dev is not installed.
 libopencv-dev depends on libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1); however:
  Package libopencv-highgui-dev is not installed.
 libopencv-dev depends on libopencv-calib3d-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1); however:
  Package libopencv-calib3d-dev is not installed.
 libopencv-dev depends on libopencv-flann-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1); however:
  Package libopencv-flann-dev is not installed.
 libopencv-dev depends on libopencv-features2d-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1); however:
  Package libopencv-features2d-dev is not installed.
 libopencv-dev depends on libopencv-legacy-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1); however:
  Package libopencv-legacy-dev is not installed.
 libopencv-dev depends on libopencv-contrib-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1); however:
  Package libopencv-contrib-dev is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libopencv-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libopencv-dev
```

---

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and still same problem... and i think getting this problem because of updating kubuntu today

Comment: You have added some PPA or something that is causing this error, can you add some detail of what PPAs you've installed in your question?

Comment: From the console did you try as mentioned above the sudo apt-get install -f? This should fi any missing dependencies that weren't installed. Also do you have PPA's configured or is this a stock install of Kubuntu? Muon is working fine on my current 11.10 and 12.04 installs of Kubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too.

Try to run these commands in the terminal ("Konsole"):

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: i try your answer : ~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libopencv-dev: libopencv-dev depends on libopencv-core-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1); however: Package libopencv-core-dev is not installed. libopencv-dev depends on libopencv-ml-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1); however: Package libopencv-ml-dev is not installed. libopencv-dev depends on libopencv-imgproc-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1); however: Package libopencv-imgproc-dev is not installed. libopencv-dev depends on libopencv-video-dev (= 2.3.1-4ppa1); however: Package libopencv-video-dev is not installed. libopencv-dev depends

Answer (score 1):

I had this too... the thing that got it working for me was to reinstall muon:

```
sudo apt-get purge muon
sudo apt-get install muon
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

`sudo apt-get -f install`.

Answer (score 0):

I had and have this problem on brand new installs.  To fix I added a newer version of Muon which is considered experimental.  Please remember there are risks using unfamiliar PPA,s so read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) if you have any questions.  The PPA I used is ppa:echidnaman/qapt form [here](https://launchpad.net/~echidnaman/+archive/qapt/) and [this](http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?56881-Muon-Software-Manager-will-not-open&p=282917&viewfull=1#post282917) is where I got the information to use this fix.